# How to prevent long table from being hidden by an image with position: fixed when printing html page

Tags: html, css

I have a multiple long html tables featuring a lot of tr lines that i want to print with a footer image, to put the image to the bottom of the table i use the 'position: fixed' css tag with 'bottom: 0', it works, but if a table is too long, it's hidden behind the footer image on the bottom of the preview page.

my html is like that

```
<div class='page-break'> (to break page after this div)
    <table>
        <tr><td>content</td></tr>
        ...lots of lines, more than 1 print page long
    </table>
    <div class='footer'><img src='footer_image' /></div>
</div>
... and repeated many times
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer is as said on this article

https://medium.com/@Idan_Co/the-ultimate-print-html-template-with-header-footer-568f415f6d2a

Basically put a div (empty) the size of your recurrent footer in the tfoot of your table.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        ... your table content
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr><td><div class='spacer'>&nbsp;</div></td></tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<div class='footer'>footer content</div>

CSS:
.spacer {
    height: 150px;
}
.footer {
    height: 150px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```